# Kernel driver - ZedBoard - Linux hangs after accessing address

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, fpga, xilinx

I am new ZedBoard. My ZedBoard running on Xilinx Linux 2015.4 (devicetree.dtb, boot.bin and uImage manually compiled; other files come from original archive with precompiled system).
I create very simple FPGA configuration only with PS, AXI GPIO and LEDs. In Vivado Address I can see this line:

```
Cell       Slave Interface Base name Offset addr. Range High addr.
axi_gpio_0 S_AXI           Reg       0x4120_0000  64K   0x4120_FFFF
```

I want create own kernel driver for this FPGA configuration but when I try insert driver into system, Linux hangs when ioread/iowrite operation starts.
There is code about init function:

```
#define DEV_NAME "my_led_dev"

dev_t dev_numbers;
struct cdev *my_led_cdev;
static unsigned long gpio_base = 0x41200000;
struct resource *res;


static int led_init(void) {
  void* kernel_gpio_base;

  /* Device registration */
  int state; 
  if ((state = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_numbers, 0, 1, DEV_NAME)) != 0)
    printk(KERN_ALERT "failed to register a region dynamically\n");
  else 
    printk(KERN_ALERT "major number = %d\n", MAJOR(dev_numbers));

  my_led_cdev = cdev_alloc();
  my_led_cdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;

  state = cdev_add(my_led_cdev, dev_numbers, 1);
  if(state < 0) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "device failed to be added\n");
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev_numbers, 1); 
    return -ENODEV;
  }
  printk (KERN_INFO "Device prepared\n");

  /* Get required resources. */
  res = request_mem_region(gpio_base, 0xFFFF, "my_gpio_led");
  if (res == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "my_gpio: can't get I/O port address 0x%lx\n", gpio_base);
    return -ENODEV;
  }

  /* Port mapping */
  kernel_gpio_base = (void*) ioremap(gpio_base, 0xFFFF);
  if (kernel_gpio_base == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "kernel remap my_gpio failed 0x%lx\n", gpio_base);
    release_mem_region (res->start, 65536);
    cdev_del(my_led_cdev); 
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev_numbers, 1); 
    return -ENODEV;
  }
  printk (KERN_INFO "Ports mapped\n");

  printk (KERN_INFO "Mapped port: %p", kernel_gpio_base);
  printk (KERN_INFO "Actual value: %d\n", ioread32 (kernel_gpio_base)); // There is problem. This message isn't printed and system hangs.
  iowrite8 (0xff, kernel_gpio_base);

  return 0;
}
```

I have seen Xilinx and ZedBoard documentation but without result. I found few topics about hanging after inserting module on Xilinx but problem was with device tree where fclk-enable was disabled. Actually I use default DT without changes and fclk-enable has value <0xf>.

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU will hang if it issues memory transactions against the programmable logic and there is not a response. There is no built-in bus error or timeout mechanism.

Here are some of the reasons I have had this problem:

1. Programmable logic is not programmed
2. AXI slave is not responding to the right address
3. Bug in AXI slave

One way to debug this would be to use the integrated logic analyzer to trace the AXI interface.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, I know that problem is in ps7_post_config. I working over the JTAG and my module not use Xilinx SDK where can be this option enabled so I seeking way how to provide this option in Vivado in bitstream (bitstream option?) or what other ways are possible.

Comment: We may have seen this problem also. We do not use the Xilinx SDK either. We generally program the Zynq via /dev/xdevcfg rather than JTAG.

Comment: Searching for ps7_post_config, I found an XML file with some processor registers to update. I think that the xdevcfg driver may be more instructive way to determine what registers need to be updated after the logic is programmed: https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/drivers/char/xilinx_devcfg.c